# How can I intercept the tweet button click event?

Tags: javascript, twitter, onclick, event-handling, dom-events

I'm developing a browser extension and I want to intercept the tweet button click event, just like in the image below:

[image: a]

I managed to get the element node like this:

```
document.querySelector('div[data-testid="tweetButton"]')
```

This is what I tried to do:

1. Override the node's "click" and "onclick" function
2. Override the node's "click" event listener, i.e. `tweetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {})`
3. Remove the "click" event listener, i.e. `tweetButton.removeEventListener("click", function() {})`
4. Repeat #1, #2 and #3 for "mousedown" and "onmousedown"
5. Add a global listener via `document.addEventListener` and check against a selector. The callback gets fired but the XHR still goes through, even if I did `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Maybe it's not this object that the event listener is attached to, but in HTML it has the "button" role, so it should be the one.

Could I achieve the same goal by listening to the Ajax request?

Comment: Your second step doesn't override the click event but adds new functionality to it. If you want to override it you would instead want to do `tweetButton.onclick = function(evt){}`

Comment: Thanks @GenericUser but unfortunately the XHR request still gets sent. Is there any way I can prevent that?

Comment: It might not hurt to verify that's the actual initiator of the XHR request. On the network tab of Chrome's debugger it lists the outgoing requests and includes a column called "Initiator". It's possible the XHR request is actually being triggered by an event on the button's parent.

You can also check on the elements tab and verify the listeners on the "Event Listeners" option in the upper right (after selecting an element).

Comment: It lists the initiator as "Other". I also went on to install the [JavaScript Tracker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-tracker/pdkjocgjcabjddpnefbdkdeadfancbgh?hl=en) extension but it only led me to this [minified piece of code](https://imgur.com/a/s8CIHVC). I added the fifth thing in the list above.

Comment: There's also the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. You could try overriding those to see if they may be playing a part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, it seems solution #2 was correct:

```
let tweetButton = document.querySelector('div[data-testid="tweetButton"]');
tweetButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

You can find here the [open-sourced code](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/tft).